# Receiving errors when trying to install virt-manager on MacOS monterey

Tags: python, macos, virtual-machine, virtualization, macos-monterey

I have been trying to install virt-manager on macOS Monterey.
I have ran these commands:
`brew install libvirt`

`brew tap arthurk/homebrew-virt-manager`

`brew install virt-manager virt-viewer`

during installation I received the following errors:

```
    /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/pkg-config --print-errors --atleast-version=0.9.11 libvirt
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/3.2.0_3/libexec/bin/python3.9 generator.py libvirt /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libvirt/8.1.0/share/libvirt/api/libvirt-api.xml
    Found 493 functions in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libvirt/8.1.0/share/libvirt/api/libvirt-api.xml
    Found 0 functions in libvirt-override-api.xml
    Generated 402 wrapper functions
    Missing type converters:
    virTypedParameterPtr:1
    int *:1
    ERROR: failed virDomainSetLaunchSecurityState
    ERROR: failed virNodeDeviceGetAutostart
    error: command '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/3.2.0_3/libexec/bin/python3.9' failed with exit code 1
    Running setup.py install for libvirt-python: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/3.2.0_3/libexec/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/virt-manager--libvirt-python-20220311-26573-1hgf5gt/libvirt-python-7.3.0/setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'/private/tmp/virt-manager--libvirt-python-20220311-26573-1hgf5gt/libvirt-python-7.3.0/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file) if os.path.exists(file) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code =
f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-cyrsgth9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/3.2.0_3/libexec/include/site/python3.9/libvirt-python Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/3.2.0_3/libexec/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  https://github.com/arthurk/homebrew-virt-manager/issues
```

I've tried source for .bash_profile however couldn't find file, so I tried creating .bash_profile however after source the file still couldn't be found.

```
.bash_profile:1: no such file or directory: export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin
baris@pc-12-151 ~ % ls -a 
.               Documents
..              Downloads
.CFUserTextEncoding     Library
.DS_Store           Movies
.Trash              Music
.bash_profile           Parallels
.runelite           Pictures
.zprofile           Public
.zsh_history            get-pip.py
.zsh_sessions           jagex_cl_oldschool_LIVE.dat
Applications (Parallels)    jagexcache
Desktop             random.dat
baris@pc-12-151 ~ % source .runelite
source: no such file or directory: .runelite
baris@pc-12-151 ~ % nano .zprofile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error as of current on macOS Monterey.
There is a PR available that resolves the problem and for now I tested it on Intel mac and it works.

Here are the commands:

```
brew untap jeffreywildman/homebrew-virt-manager
brew tap rombarcz/homebrew-virt-manager
brew install virt-manager
```

Here is also the pr:

```
https://github.com/Krish-sysadmin/homebrew-virt-manager/pull/2
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, after running `brew services start libvirt` and `virt-manager -c "qemu:///session" --no-fork` I am not able to create a new virtual machine and the following error shows: 'Error: Host does not support any virtualisation options' [https://imgur.com/a/8CvNcpC]

Comment: Just do virt-manager in terminal ideally after you added you ssh key to your agent so you don't get constant pings for your ssh password. If this answered your question please mark it as the answer.